# Positioning a canvas in the main window

Tags: wpf, canvas

I have the following code that creates a canvas on the fly:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Height = 300;
        canvas.Width = 275;
        canvas.Background = Brushes.Blue;

        this.AddChild(canvas);
        ...
    }
```

There is nothing in the corresponding XAML except the boilerplate MainWindow definition generated by Visual Studio (I have deleted the Grid entry that VS supplies by default):

```
<Window x:Class="canvas2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Gray">
</Window>
```

The code centers the canvas in the middle of the application main window.  How can I position the canvas myself, through the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would usually have some kind of top-level container in your Window, perhaps another Canvas:

```
<Window ...>
    <Canvas Name="root"/>
</Window>
```

Now you would add your Canvas to the root Canvas:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Height = 300;
canvas.Width = 275;
canvas.Background = Brushes.Blue;

// set child canvas position
Canvas.SetLeft(canvas, ...);
Canvas.SetTop(canvas, ...);

// add child canvas to root
root.Children.Add(canvas);
```

---

Perhaps the most important thing to know about [WPF Panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx) like Grid, Canvas, etc. is that they can be nested. You could for example put a Canvas into a Grid, and put that into another Grid, as often as you like.

The top-level Panel however, be it a Grid or Canvas or whatever, is set to the `Content` property of the Window. In code you could do that like show below, but there is hardly any reason to do so.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var rootPanel = ...;
    Content = rootPanel;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I did not know that you had to have a top level container.  This key point pretty much solves everything.  Just one additional question: is root a WPF concept, or is it the top level canvas which is named root [i.e. Canvas root = new Canvas()].  Thanks again.

Comment: "root" is just the name I assigned to the top-level Canvas in XAML: `<Canvas Name="root"/>`. The important thing is that the top-level container is the `Content` of the Window, which is also done in XAML simply by putting it between `<Window>` and `</Window>`. You could of course use any other name you like. If you don't like to give it a name at all, you could also retrieve it in code like so: `var topLevelContainer = Content as Panel;`

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should specify what you mean for "position".

You can specify the Margin property of the Canvas, so that it will be positioned accordingly to the container (the Window). However, consider also the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment property, which work together with the Margin.

Maybe you mean an "absolute" positioning, instead. For instance, position the canvas at a certain point/size, independently from the container size. In that case, the simplest way is to placing a Canvas inside another Canvas, then position the inner one by setting the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top property. Of course you should specify the Width and Height as well.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Mario Vernari, your solution ("placing a Canvas inside another Canvas") was helpful in confirming Clemens' solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: ive just found this solution myself, then ive read this LULLL